# Defining a service offered (sold) by a local business using schema.org

Tags: schema.org, microdata

I have a website where people can compare driving schools. I've added alle the details (name, description, location, pricerange, etc.) I know about these schools to their pages on my website, using the schema.org markups.

Since a few weeks, people can also buy (read: book) their first driving lesson offered by the schools on my website, directly on my website. I was searching for a way to add this to the schema.org markup at my pages, but I don't really know what to use in my case.

I think of the two following possibilties. Can you tell me which one I should use? Or that you may think of a better solution?

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
    <div itemprop="name">...</div>
    <div itemprop="description">...</div>
    <div itemprop="priceRange">...</div>
    <div itemprop="makesOffer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <div itemprop="name">...</div>
        <div itemprop="price">...</div>
        <div itemprop="priceCurrency">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness">
    <div itemprop="name">...</div>
    <div itemprop="description">...</div>
    <div itemprop="priceRange">...</div>
    <div itemprop="owns" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
        <div itemprop="name">...</div>
        <div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
            <div itemprop="price">...</div>
            <div itemprop="priceCurrency">...</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At last, I was looking for a better schema type for driving schools, but I don't think they have specified driving schools. Do you think it is better to use ProfessionalService instead of LocalBusiness?

Answer (score 0):

I think both of your examples are possible.

If you don’t have any specific requirements from consumers you expect to make use of your markup, I’d go with the first example: `LocalBusiness` → `makesOffer` → `Offer`.

It seems that you don’t really need the `Product` item, as you are only using the `name` property, which could be used on the `Offer` instead.

Comment: What sort of requirements from consumers are you talkin about? Why is that important for choosing the first or the second?

Comment: @Ronald01990: Just that there might be cases where a given consumer (like a search engine) might need data marked up in a certain way.

Comment: The markup is especially for search engines of course, but I guess you've assumed that. And do you think I should rather user ProfessionalService instead of LocalBusiness for driving schools?